# Biholomorphic Mapping on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

The german Wikipedia page states that the inversion $\frac{1}{z}$ is a biholomorphism from the unit disk $ \mathbb{D} := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ to $\mathbb{C} \backslash \overline{\mathbb{D}} $ where $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ denotes the closed unit disk. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphe_Abbildung

First of all, I am confused about $z=0$, because it would imply (on the Riemann sphere) $1/0 = \infty $ where $\infty \notin \mathbb{C}$. My Intuition tells me that this is not possible since $\mathbb{D}$ is simply connected whereas $\mathbb{C} \backslash \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is not.

Can we state then $f: \mathbb{D}\backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{C} \backslash \overline{\mathbb{D}} $ is a Biholomorphism?
And in general: Let U be an open, connected and simply connected space $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ (such as $\mathbb{D}$) and P an open twice connected (?) space in $\mathbb{C}$. Does there exist a biholomorphism between U and P ? The Riemann Mapping theorem states that  connected and  simply connected open Subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are Biholomorphic, but it doesn't state that there is no possible Biholomorphism for the above example.

Comment: Quote: "Bei ihr wird das Innere des Kreises mit Radius = 1 (sog. Einheitskreis) auf das Äußere, das Äußere in das Innere abgebildet, der Rand des Kreises geht in sich selber über."
so they just say the inside of the unit circle, and do not exclude the point 0

Comment: That's what I thought. But what about the "adjusted" statement?

Comment: They are sloppy. In general, it's not a good idea to learn math from Wikipedia only. The correct statement is that the inversion is a biholomorphic map from the open unit disk to $\widehat{\mathbb C} \setminus cl(D)$, where $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is the Riemann sphere. What difficulty do you have proving that the inversion is a biholomorphic map from the punctured unit disk to ${\matbb C}\setminus cl(D)$? Do you have trouble proving holomorphicity? Or invertibility?...